# Shell scripting, loop through folders

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large series of subfolders on my Mac with a random amount of csv files in each one. What I'd like to do is merge these files into a single file for each directory.

So far I know I can merge these files with `cat * > mergedfile.csv`, but I'm having issues iterating through all the folders. I somehow managed to merge all sorts of things so far, but I can't seem to make this do what I want exactly.

Any idea on the best way to do this?

```
for DIR in ./subfolder/*
do
    cat $dir/* > merged.csv 
done
```

Comment: `$DIR` and `$dir` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

With `find`, you can recursively list all files that match a certain criterion, e.g. the file name.

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.csv"); do cat "$file" >> /path/to/output.csv; done
```

Breaking it up, `find . -name "*.csv"` will find all CSV files from the current folder you're in (`.`), and the loop will just iterate over that list, appending everything to the `output.csv` file.

**But:** File names with spaces, globbing characters, and newlines can be tricky here. A safer solution would be to just use `exec` for the find command.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cat '{}' >> /path/to/output.csv ';'
```

Here, `'{}'` will be replaced by find with the filename. For a long Q&A about why this is and how to circumvent the problem [can be found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names).

Now, if you want to create one CSV file for each directory – sorry, didn't see that before –, I'd probably do something like this:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d); do find $dir -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -exec cat {} >> "$dir/out" ';'; mv "$dir/out" "$dir/merged.csv"; done
```

Although Franck's solution below is probably more efficient.

---

Of course, pay attention to the difference between `>` and `>>`. The former will always truncate the file to zero-length before writing to it, whereas the latter will just append to the file.

The reason why `cat *.csv > merged.csv` worked—and why in your loop, it won't work—is that the shell will expand the wildcard before, so basically it sees:

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv > merged.csv
```

… which will of course not overwrite anything.

Answer (score 1):

Into the parent folder :

```
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
  cd $dir
  [[ $(ls *.csv|wc -l) -eq 0 ]] 2> /dev/null || { print "$dir.csv created";
                                                  cat *.csv > $dir.csv; }
  cd - > /dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash 4+ (check with `bash --version`), you can activate globstar with `shopt -s globstar` and loop through all directories (and only directories - the trailing `/` rules out files) recursively with `**/`

```
for f in **/; do cat "$f"/*.csv > "$f"/merged.csv; done
```

If you genuinely want to use *all* files in a directory, rather than just those ending in `.csv`, then

```
for f in **/; do cat "$f"/* > "$f"/merged.csv; done
```

If you only want to go down a single level, rather than being fully recursive, then use `*/` rather than `**/`.

The key mistake in the OP script (aside from forgetting that bash is case-sensitive) is that it attempts to write the contents of *all* the files into a single `.csv` file, and does it in such a way as each iteration of the loop would over-write the last.

If you wanted to concatenate *all* the `.csv` files recursively into a single file, you could again use globstar

```
for f in **/*.csv; do cat "$f" > merged_all.csv
```